# How to insert only one image into database codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi all I am a new of codeigniter I have problam with insert image into database
I have 3 image form upload . When I insert image 1 ,2 and 3 into database it's ok. nut when I insert image 1 into database and image 2 and 3 is empty it has the error is :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: img2

Filename: mbl-admin/Site_admin.php

Line Number: 153

Backtrace:

File: /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/application/controllers/mbl-admin/Site_admin.php
Line: 153
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: img3

Filename: mbl-admin/Site_admin.php

Line Number: 154

Backtrace:

File: /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/application/controllers/mbl-admin/Site_admin.php
Line: 154
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/application/controllers/mbl-admin/Site_admin.php
Line: 157
Function: redirect

File: /home/wwwmyburgerlabco/public_html/mbl/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

how can I do it .this is my code in controller:

```
function burger_add(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './images/burger/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 3500;
        $config['max_width']            = 4800;
         $config['max_height']           = 3200;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile2'))
        {
           $img2 = $this->upload->data();
        }
        if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile3'))
        {
           $img3 = $this->upload->data();
        }
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required|trim');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('category','Category','required|trim');
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile1') || ($this->form_validation->run() == false))
                {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('admin_view/header_admin');
                $this->load->view('admin_view/burger_add',$error);
                $this->load->view('admin_view/footer_admin');
                }
                else{
                  $img1 = $this->upload->data();
                    $insert = array(
                      'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                      'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                      'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                      'image' => $img1['file_name'],
                       'image2' => $img2['file_name'],
                      'image3' => $img3['file_name'],
                      );
                    $this->db->insert('product',$insert);
                        redirect('mbl-admin/Site_admin/burger_add_form');
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Some itme I have only 1 image to upload and  sometime I have 2 image or 3 .it depend on imgae . I upload 3 image it ok . but when I upload 1 or 2 image it has error

Comment: do u gave some code for me and help me pleaste ?

Comment: yes some time I need insert 1st image to DB and next all empty image

Comment: yes brother also in db

Comment: and some time I need upload 2 image insert to db it depend on me Ihave 1 or 2 or 3 image

Comment: now can you help me brother ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `error_reporting(0)` in your function `burger_add()` to remove notice error.

Like this -

```
function burger_add(){

    error_reporting(0);

 # here write your code

}
```

And you have to turn on output buffering in your constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    ob_start();

}
```

After adding [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) you've never encountered the message "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output)" .

ATTENTION: Suppressing errors or temporary disabling error reporting does NOT solve the problem, it just hides the error / warning message.

Comment: I add error_reporting(0) it ok but when I add public function __construct()
{
    ob_start();

} it has errror

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Site_admin::$session

Filename: mbl-admin/Site_admin.php

Line Number: 16

Answer (score 1):

> Try this code.single image upload in codeigniter 3.0.1

```
function burger_add(){

    $config['upload_path']          = './images/burger/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 3500;
        $config['max_width']            = 4800;
         $config['max_height']           = 3200;

            $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile2')) 
            { 
                $error = ['error' => $this->upload->display_errors()];
                $this->load->view('admin_view/burger_add', $error);
            }
            else
            {

                $uploaddata = $this->upload->data();

                foreach ($uploaddata as $value)
                {

                    $data = [
                                'name' => $value['file_name'],
                                'type' => $value['file_type'],
                                'category' => 'news'
                            ];
                    $this->Image_model->image($data);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Some itme I have only 1 image to upload and sometime I have 2 image or 3 .it depend on imgae . I upload 3 image it ok . but when I upload 1 or 2 image it has error

Comment: i think you need to multiple image upload function

Comment: 3 image upload in to db?

Comment: some time 1 image some time 2 some  time 3 it depend on I have image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94891/discussion-between-naseeba-c-and-user307709).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CI but *do_upload* sounds not like a method that could be used to check if a upload item exists.

Edit: i have discovered the CI docs a bit. It is indeed the method to check if a specific upload field does ( or uploads in general does ) exists.

So all you have to do is to check if a specific field exists ( along the do_upload(fieldname) method ) and execute the upload task inside the if-body for the specific field, thats all.

Its hard to define that source by hand on a smartphone, but i think you can easily define the source by yourself.